# how to specify concatenation two columns into new column in insert statment

Tags: python, mysql

I have this table in mysql

```
`id`,`camera_id`,`image_id`,`name`,`plate`,`datetime`,`millisecs`,`nationality`,`image_name`,`image`,`checked`).
```

I want to concatenate  `id` and `camera_id` into `image_id`,  where can i specify concatenate in this script.'Id' is  the primary key with auto increment and  camera_id is the id of the camera.

```
def insert_entry(self, camId, camName, vrm, entryDatetime, milliSecs, nationality, filename):
        myFilename = "/tmp/%s" % filename

        fullOldPlate = re.compile('^\D\d{3}\D{3}$')
        fullNewPlate = re.compile('^\D{2}[05]\d\D{3}$')

        tableName = "customer_1.%s_anpr_vega" % camName
        #os.chown(myFilename,116,123)
        #os.chmod(myFilename, 438)

        checked = 0
        if(fullOldPlate.match(vrm)):
            checked = 1
        elif(fullNewPlate.match(vrm)):
            checked = 1

        sql = """INSERT INTO %s (camera_id, name, plate, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name,checked)
        values ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (tableName,
                                                       camId,
                                                       camName,
                                                       vrm,
                                                       entryDatetime,
                                                       milliSecs,
                                                       nationality,
                                                       filename,
                                                       checked)
        # print sql
        retVal = self.cursor.execute(sql)

        # Now get the id of the entry we have just created
        sql = """SELECT id FROM %s ORDER BY id DESC""" % tableName
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        tmp = self.cursor.fetchone()
        myId = tmp[0]

        sql = """UPDATE %s SET IMAGE=LOAD_FILE('%s') WHERE id = "%s" """ % (tableName,
            myFilename,
            myId)
        #self.cursor.execute(sql)
        # Remove the image file
        #os.remove(myFilename)

        return myId
```

Comment: First, In which language you have written above code?

You can use something like
`image_id = image_id % "_" % camId`

Comment: `image_id = "test_%s_%s" (image_id, camId)`
Reff: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python

Comment: Ashwin thanks for that.. but the issue is  Id is created after the insert statment where image_id = (ID + cam_id) If i use your syntax image_id = id %"_" %camId  the Id is not created in the insert statment.

Comment: From a database design point of view, you shouldn't do that at all.  If the `id` and `camera_id` column have all the information, then no additional column with just the information combined should be inserted.  Just concatenate the strings on-demand.  But if you really want to do it, I think you'll need to go the INSERT-SELECT-UPDATE route.

Comment: And please fix your code display.  I would edit it if I knew what you've meant it to be.  This is not valid Python syntax.  Also maybe tag your question with SQL.

Comment: Thanks 5gon12eder .. I have edited my code and now you can see it is valid python script